# Maintaining page centering with uneven divs on the sides

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css, jsx

Here is what I want:
[image]

Here is what I'm getting:

[image: ![![enter image description here]

DIV1 is centered in the center of the page

Here is my code using tailwind:

```
    <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center mt-10">
        <div className="flex items-center justify-center w-128 my-4">
            <DIV1 />
        </div>
        <div className="flex">
          <div className="p-8 max-w-xs">
            <DIV2 />
          </div>
          <div className="p-8 w-[500px]">
            <DIV3 />
          </div>
          <div className="p-8">
            <DIV4 />
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The thing with tailwind is I can only adjust the width in increments larger than 1 so I can't adjust it to be exactly center. Even so I'm looking for a better way to do this without manually adjust the precise pixel width so that it will work on any screen size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to have elements following the same grid on both axis, you need to use CSS Grid instead of Flex. Here’s a basic example based on your drawings:

```html
<div class="grid grid-cols-[minmax(auto,20rem)_500px_1fr]">
  <div class="col-start-2 bg-red-100">1</div>
  <div class="row-start-2 bg-violet-100">2</div>
  <div class="row-start-2 bg-blue-100">3</div>
  <div class="row-start-2 bg-cyan-100">4</div>
</div>
```

This is Tailwind specific syntax though, but it translates easily to CSS:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(auto, 20rem) 500px 1fr;
}
```

[Interactive playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/RCLRnHTkyd)